2 Corinthians 5:1-8 - - What's in the tent?
2 Corinthians 5:1-8 (ESV)
(1) For we know that if the tent that is our earthly home is destroyed, we have a building (οἰκοδομὴν) from God, a house not made with hands, eternal (αἰώνιον) in the heavens (οὐρανοῖς). (2) For in this tent (σκήνους) we groan, longing to put on our heavenly dwelling (οἰκητήριον ἡμῶν τὸ ἐξ οὐρανοῦ), (3) if indeed by putting it ona we may not be found naked. (4) For while we are still in this tent, we groan, being burdened—not that we would be unclothed, but that we would be further clothed, so that what is mortal may be swallowed up by life. (5) He who has prepared us for this very thing is God, who has given us the Spirit as a guarantee. (6) So we are always of good courage. We know that while we are at home in the body (ἐνδημοῦντες ἐν τῷ σώματι) we are away from the Lord, (7) for we walk by faith, not by sight. (8) Yes, we are of good courage, and we would rather be away from the body and at home with the Lord (ἐνδημῆσαι πρὸς τὸν Κύριον).

If:-

Adam is made a living soul by God's breathing into him (Genesis 2:7)

The spirit of God dwells in the temple (Haggai 2:4-5)

Some of the terms Paul uses for our tents and houses correspond to descriptions of God's temple.



σκηνῆ=מִקְדָּ֑שׁ refers to the Tabernacle at Exodus 25:8


οἰκοδομὴ=הַבִּירָ֔ה refers to the Temple at 1 Chronicles 29  [in LXX this might be a textual variant?]


From 2Cor.5:1, we don't end when the body ends

In 2Cor.5:6-8, 'be at home' might lose some of the sense of ἐνδημῆσαι since that refers to the body-politic not the household



Then:-
Is it that the breath of God makes itself a temple of the heavens and the earth in Genesis 1:2... which is analogous to the breath of God entering Adam... which is analogous to the shekhinah in the Tabernacle and the Temple... which is here analogous to our selves in the tent of the physical body?
And if so, what is the heavenly house - is it that the portion of the breath that went into Adam remains individuated, pending later exhalation, and isn't reabsorbed into God? It's not that there's some big rack and you take your ticket to claim the right clone.
Where Paul doesn't leave us exposed (1:3), is that analogous to the sanctity of God and his inviolable oneness? That even the portion of the breath is too sacred to come directly in contact with the Deep?
And ἐνδημῆσαι doesn't imply our physical death triggers an urgent construction project in Heaven, does it? It's that the οἰκοδομὴ was always there and Adam is gradually returning to it sanctified by Christ.

There have been previous relevant questions but from other angles:-
Did Paul believe that his "self" was inside his body? 2 Corinthians 5:1-10
Our "tent" - Discarded or resurrected?

The OP's question is answered by Paul in 2 Cor 5:1 (quoted by the OP) -

For we know that if the tent that is our earthly home is
destroyed, we have a building (οἰκοδομὴν) from God, a house not made
with hands, eternal (αἰώνιον) in the heavens (οὐρανοῖς).

From this we learn several things:

Paul is using the metaphor of a "tent" to describe our earthly bodies
Paul is making a distinction between our earthly bodies and those which we will receive at the resurrection, which in 1 Cor 15 he calls our "heavenly bodies".
that our earthly bodies will be destroyed to be replaced by heavenly bodies

However, it is also clear that whether we have earthly bodies or heavenly bodies, all are completely dependent on God for life and existence, as per Col 1:15-18, 1 John 5:11, 12.

1 Corinthians 15:44 - does ἐγείρεται refer to a replacement physical body being raised out of the new earth by heaven, or to the spirit 'rising' from its abode on earth to its abode in heaven?

@FelixLXX - 1 Cor 15:39-51 says we get a brand-new heavenly body at the resurrection.

Is the σῶμα πνευματικόν of 1Cor.15:44 the same as the οἰκίαν ἀχειροποίητον of 2Cor.5:1 ? Or is the spirit-body raised into the house not-made-with-hands? The σῶμα πνευματικόν isn't brand-new is it? He says it's there if=whenever there is a σῶμα ψυχικόν.

@FelixLXX - this question is answered in 1 Cor 15:40-45 and is distinct from that above.
